# »Köln ist einfach korrekt«. Warum »korrekt«?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Ich habe [ein Lied](http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/wise-guys/koln-ist-einfach-korrekt-53c7eb09.html) der deutschen Band Wise Guys gehört und habe dieser Ausdruck darin bemerkt:

> Ich kann’s nicht beschreiben,
>   doch ich werd’ wohl hier bleiben,
>   egal, ob’s dir schmeckt:
>   Köln ist einfach korrekt!

Ich verstehe, dass *korrekt* hier *toll* bedeutet.

Kann dieses Wort immer *toll* bedeuten? Kann man »Das ist korrekt!« umgangssprachlich sagen?

Comment: Jugendsprache, in der Schweiz hauptsächlich durch Einwanderer aus dem Balkan geprägt. Vorteil in diesem Fall: es reimt!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, das kann man durchaus mit "toll" übersetzen. Da ist aber auch noch die Konnotation von "ohne Makel" dabei, vermutlich bezogen auf die Ansprüche des Autors an die Stadt, die Lebensmittelpunkt sein soll. "Egal ob's dir schmeckt" ist evtl. noch ein Bezug darauf, dass Köln eben entsprechend der subjektiv wichtigen Kriterien "in Ordnung" ist, unabhängig davon, was Andere an der Stadt zu bemängeln haben. Man sagt auch über einen Menschen: "ey kannst nix sagen, der is voll korrekt".

Edit: Sowohl dieses Beispiel als auch das ursprüngliche Beispiel des Fragestellers sind durchaus als jugendsprachlich einzuordnen und ich hätte das schon ursprünglich anmerken sollen (Danke Takkat!) Ein anderer Kommentar weist darauf hin, dass man diesen Sprachgebrauch in der Schweiz mit Einwanderern aus dem Balkan verbindet. In Deutschland (ohne in irgendeiner Form rassistisch sein zu wollen) würde ich sagen dass "korrekt" in dieser Form eher Jugendlichen mit türkischem Hintergrund zugewiesen werden würde, die Verbreitung ist aber längst darüber hinausgewachsen. Ein weiteres Schlagwort wäre "Hip-Hop".

Comment: Ich würde sagen, korrekt für prima, toll ist sehr regionaler Sprachgebrauch. In Standarddeutsch hat korrekt diese Bedeutung nicht.

Comment: Nein, das ist definitiv Jugendsprache, vermutlich nur vereinzelter sozialer Millieus. Andererseits kommt aus diesen Ecken einiges an Spracherneuerung, die dann mit dem Älterwerden dieser Generationen auch mehr und mehr in die kolloquiale Allgemeinsprache übergeht. Interessant ist übrigens, dass der Duden (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/korrekt) auch "einwandfrei" u.ä. als Bedeutungen angibt. Die "Jugendsprache" divergiert hier also nur bei oberflächlicher Betrachtung vom Standardgebrauch.

Comment: Ich stimme @rogermue zu. Es ist genausowenig Standarddeutsch wie 'dufte'. Dass die Jugendsprache nur oberflächlich divergiere,,würde ich nicht sagen. Das mag objektiv zutreffen, für den Jugendlichen aber ist "einwandfrei" wohl kaum "korrekt", da die gewisse "Chilligkeit" fehlt :P

Comment: Weder Hip-Hop noch Einwanderer, auch schon lange nicht mehr jugendlich (auch schon 1980, als das Lied erschien, mit um die dreißig nicht mehr wirklich), aber es reimt sich auch hier: ["Mal eben nach Jamaika fliegen,
das würd mir liegen.
Zu 'ner Rasta-Party mit Sekt,
das wär korrekt."](http://genius.com/Ideal-luxus-lyrics).